# Don't show output of "cd -<#>"

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

In oh-my-zsh, doing a `cd -` outputs the target directory, which is redundant since my shell prompt shows the relative working directory.

I understand I can do `cd - > /dev/null`, but I'd have to type that out every single time. Is there a quick and easy way to make this work, including ones with numbers (e.g., `cd -2`)?

I tried setting `setopt pushd_silent`, but no luck.

Here is the config that oh-my-zsh uses: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/directories.zsh

Comment: Why are you typing `cd -`? Do you have a directory actually named `-` you want to cd into?

Comment: @Xen2050 `cd -` will change to the previous directory... you can use it to toggle back and forth.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I figured `help cd` (didn't mention the dash) would've been about the same as in `man bash` (where it does say `-` expands to $OLDPWD)

Answer (score 2):

```
function cd {
  builtin cd "$@" > /dev/null 
}
```

I got it working with the code above. Not sure if there's a better way, though.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently an alias works too, redirects stdout and leaves stderr:

```
~/Downloads$ alias cd
bash: alias: cd: not found
~/Downloads$ alias cd='cd >/dev/null'
~/Downloads$ cd ~/Videos
~/Videos$ cd -
~/Downloads$ cd fake
bash: cd: fake: No such file or directory
```

(prompt above prints the current directory first)